# Count if text appears in multiple columns in a row

Tags: excel, count, block, schedule

Essentially I am looking at a schedule and trying to figure out how many times a person worked a block - meaning their name will appear in columns side by side.

Each column represents a day of the week. So if John worked Mon - Tues that counts as a block and his name would appear in 2 columns. He then may work Thurs - Sat and that counts as a block. I need to figure out how often this occurs over the course of a month.

Manual counting using conditional formatting is one option - but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Thanks for your help all, It is much appreciated!

Comment: So is your desired answer 2 for 2 separate blocks of consecutive entries?  Or would the desired answer be 5 for 5 total days worked?

Comment: Will any given employee's name always appear on the same row or anywhere in a given column?

Comment: Samantha, It may be beneficial to provide an example data set and expected results to help understand how you want the data presented

Comment: what you have either undisclosed or not been aware of is that this is not a specific programming question so much as an algorithm puzzle. it less to do with the programming language than it does with resolving the algorithm that produces the correct result. If someone works a 3 day 'block' then they have also worked at least two 2 day blocks and you need a way to avoid double counting. It's the same as a single 4 day block producing false positives for 2 @ 3 day blocks and 3 @ 2 day blocks. To further complicate matters, you haven't disclosed what happens over a weekend or month-to-month.

Comment: In short, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an algorithm problem not specific to any programming language and best asked on another SO site like [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) or even [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Comment: tigeravatar it would be 2 for 2 separate blocks of text.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution in Excel, If John's schedule for the month is in row 2 (range `B2:AF2`), then try this for the number of blocks he worked (enter as an array formula with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=SUM(--(IFERROR((B2:AF2="John")+(C2:AF2<>"John"),(AF2="John")+1)=2))
```

This assumes that if John worked a single day without working the day before or day after, it would still count as a block. Also, Note that if your schedule may contain error values (e.g., from being filled in with a formula), you'll need to wrap the schedule with `IFERROR`:

```
=SUM(--(IFERROR((IFERROR(B2:AF2,"")="John")+(IFERROR(C2:AF2,"")<>"John"),(AF2="John")+1)=2))
```